Which communities start religious observances with the Suklambaradharam prayer?
https://greenmesg.org/stotras/ganesha/shuklambaradharam_vishnum.php

शुक्लाम्बरधरं विष्णुं शशिवर्णं चतुर्भुजम् ।
प्रसन्नवदनं ध्यायेत् सर्वविघ्नोपशान्तये ॥


Shukla-Ambara-Dharam Vissnnum Shashi-Varnnam Catur-Bhujam |
Prasanna-Vadanam Dhyaayet Sarva-Vighno[a-U]pashaantaye ||


Meaning:
1: (We Meditate on Sri Ganesha) Who is wearing White Clothes, Who is All-Pervading, Who is Bright in Appearance like the Moon and Who is having Four Arms,
2: Who is having a Compassionate and Gracious Face; One should Meditate on Him to ward of all Obstacles.

Among Tamil people "Pillaiyar Suzhi"  பிள்ளையார் சுழி or Ganesa's circle is synonymous with "beginning".
Many Non-Vaishnavites would invoke Ganesa at the beginning of religious observances.
Since Vaishnavites claim this verse refers to Vishnu, they can also use it start ceremonies.
How prevalent is the use of the Suklambaradharam verse to initiate ceremonies among different Hindu communities by Geography/Sect?

This is used to invoke Vishvakasena, who is equivalent to Ganapati in Sri Vaishanava Sampradaya! So, on their part, using this is justified. Other Sampradayas have their own invocation of Ganapati and not necessarily the same shloka be implied for invoking Ganapati for them ! Tho this purely depends more upon what one's Guru Parampara follows.
